# Why this parameterized SQL takes forever when the same hardcoded one executes in no time

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, sql-server-profiler

I've got a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT ct, 
       text AS ST, 
       kval.idkwd 
FROM   (SELECT ST = kv.idkwd, 
               Count(kv.idkwd) CT, 
               kv.idkwd 
        FROM   mwf 
               INNER JOIN info 
                       ON mwf.ident = info.idinfo
               INNER JOIN rel 
                       ON rel.idinfo = info.idinfo
               INNER JOIN pers 
                       ON pers.idpers = rel.idpers 
               LEFT JOIN kwd kv 
                      ON kv.idkwd = info.kwsvstatus 
        WHERE  mwf.id IN ( :mwfIds) 
        GROUP  BY idkwd) kw 
       INNER JOIN kwd kval 
               ON kw.idkwd = kval.idkwd 
ORDER  BY text
```

From a ASP.NET application, this query is executed this way, using NHibernate:

```
session.CreateQuery(query);
query.SetParameterList("mwfIds", mwfIds, NHibernateUtil.Guid);
return query.List();
```

For a reason unknown, it sometimes takes 30 seconds to run (for some given parameters). The measures are given by SQL Profiler.

I tried executing this same query with the same parameters on SSMS (copied from the SQL Profiler output), and it runs in less than 1 second.

Worse, if I change the C# code to

```
session.CreateQuery(hardcodedQuery);
return query.List();
```

where `hardcodedQuery` is the same query I ran in  SSMS (i.e. the same as always, only without any parameter set using NH), it also runs in less than 1 second.

Why does the parameterized query take so much time ?

Comment: It is almost certainly parameter sniffing. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: @SeanLange, I thought parameter sniffing only happens in stored procedures. Am I wrong?

Comment: one more hint is, use "inner hash join" instead of "inner join" to see if it does make a difference. you also can make it a stored procedure and try to see any cnahges

Comment: @SeanLange Same as FLICKER, your link only refers to stored procs, my query isn't.

Comment: please read my second comment again, I just changed it :)

Comment: I would be extremely wary of join hints. This tells the sql engine that you know more about how to make the join than the optimizer does. This is a slippery slope for sure. It may be that it helps today but when the size of the table changes that join hint may make things even worse.

Comment: @FLICKER inner hash join was just magical. Didn't think of it, as I read somewhere that it wasn't a good idea to use hints ? Why do this hint change anything when executed by NH compared to executing it directly in SSMS ?

Comment: Could turn this into a stored proc so you aren't forced to use join hints? You would get the best of worlds.

Comment: If you run the missing index script from Dave Pinall (link at the end), does it return any missing indices for any of the tables in your query ? Link: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/03/sql-server-2008-missing-index-script-download/

Comment: If a `HASH JOIN` helps there is a good chance that youyr statistics are out of date, you can run `sp_update_stats` to get these updated. Please try this on a DEV server first.

Comment: @X.L.Ant, I agree with Jaco. I had this experience before. that's why I suggested to you. I'm glad it helped. I post the solution as answer so I get a point and people find it easier :)

Comment: Is Profiler capturing "CPU" and "Reads"?  How do those numbers compare between NHibernate and SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said by Sean Lange [in his comment](/questions/36042121/why-this-parameterized-sql-takes-forever-when-the-same-hardcoded-one-executes-in#comment59733106_36042121) this behavior is very likely to be caused by parameter sniffing.

In my experience, it has always been solved by fixing the indexes. (Do not add indexes too quickly, having too many indexes may causes other performance issues. Like bad index choices by the query optimizer, leading to temp db spills by example.)

Parameter sniffing does not occur only on stored procedure. By examples, it occurs on sql queries executed through `sp_executesql` or `EXEC()`. It may even occurs with auto-parameterized scalar values founded in queries.

Parameter sniffing is an optimization fall-back used by SQL Server in case of missing indexes. It shapes a query plans generated for a first query with its specific parameters values, which then get cached in query plan cache. All subsequent call to the same query with different parameters values, with similar connection properties, will then use that query plan, whatever the parameters values are.

If the values of the first query call was corresponding to a corner case yielding a high filtering condition from one table, but others calls values do not cause the same high filtering, the cached query plan causes them to badly perform.

SSMS has rarely the same connection options than your application, causing it to not reuse the cached query plan used by the application. Another query plan gets generated, adapted to the query parameters values you are testing if you are lacking indexes. So SSMS appears to perform better... But no, it does just use a query plan tailored for the specific parameters values you are testing.

A more detailed, precise and adequate explanation can be read in [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? *Understanding Performance Mysteries*](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) blog post.

Do not be deterred by its raw aspect, this blog is a great resource in my opinion. Do not either be fooled by the *How SQL Server Compiles a Stored Procedure* heading, he writes in the second sentence following it:

> If your application does not use stored procedures, but submits SQL statements directly, most of what I say this chapter is still applicable.

This blog post will also give you guidance on how to resolve such issues.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of out-dated statistics. Please use "inner hash join" instead of "inner join". it possible makes a difference.

Or you can update statistics regularly (or use auto update statistics) if practical. Updating statistics may take long if your table is huge though.

Comment: Why not update the statistics instead of a join hint?

Comment: In my case, the table had more more than billion records and growing by millions, every day. updating statistics was taking longer than acceptable delay. But as you said, it is another solution if practical.I updated my answer with that suggestion. Thanks.